# AWS Application Load Balancer - Path Based Routing

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I have just setup a new ALB and configured it to work on a path-based routing.

Let's say I configure the path to be /production and on the server side I'm getting the GET /production request which my server doesn't seem to understand.

How can I configure my Apache to server this "/production" request?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the question related to AWS ALB? It seems it's only related to routing in Apache.

Comment: It sounds like you were expecting that the path prefix `/production` would be absorbed by the balancer, so `GET /production/foo` would appear to the web server as `GET /foo`... so your question appears to be about how to configure apache to do an internal rewrite.